# Spring Boot 2.1 with embedded Tomcat with http/2 and ssl, gzip not working

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, compression, http2, tomcat9

In my application with Spring Boot 2.1 and with an embedded Tomcat 9 and with http2 the compression only works before the ssl encryption is added. After adding the encryption the compression is no longer active.
The application.properties file looks like this:

```
server.port: 8443
security.require-ssl=true
server.ssl.key-store:XXX
server.ssl.key-store-password: XXX
server.ssl.keyStoreType: XXX
server.ssl.keyAlias: XXX
security.jwt.token.secret-key=XXX
security.jwt.token.expire-length=XXX
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=test
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
server.compression.enabled=true
server.http2.enabled=true
server.compression.mime-types=text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json,application/xml 
server.compression.min-response-size=2KB
```

How do I enable compression to save bandwidth?

Answer (score 0):

Do you try the following

```
spring.http.gzip.enabled=true
```

for more information see the link below.

[https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/common-application-properties.html][1]

Comment: I have added the property but it had no effect.